# PHP SOAP doesn't work but wget works

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I have to make a request to a SOAP webservice and I was using the following code with success.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://myhost.foo/ws/ws.asmx?WSDL', 
    array('cache_wsdl' => false,
          'trace' => false,
          'exceptions'=>false,
          'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));

$params['method']['param'] = $somedata;
$params['method']['clientIP'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$result = $client->__soapCall('method', $params);
```

I started to receive the following error these days, at the first line of code:

```
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load 
from 'http://myhost.foo/ws/ws.asmx?WSDL' : Start tag expected, 
'<' not found
```

Trying to debug the problem, I tested the webservice with wget and the response is correct.

```
wget http://myhost.foo/ws/ws.asmx?WSDL --post-file=post.xml 
--header="Content-Type: text/xml" -O response.xml
```

I'd like to know what I am doing wrong on this line:
    $client = new SoapClient('http://myhost.foo/ws/ws.asmx?WSDL', 
        array('cache_wsdl' => false,
              'trace' => false,
              'exceptions'=>false,
              'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));

**EDIT:**

If I get the WSDL content and put on a xml file and use it locally, everything works.

```
$client = new SoapClient('wsdl.xml', array(
    'location'=> 'http://myhost.foo/ws/ws.asmx', 
    'uri'=> 'http://tempuri.org/', 
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
    'trace' => true, 
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
    'keep_alive' => false));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue just started, it suggests something has changed on the datasource side.

I'd suggest making sure that there wasn't a change of SSL Certificate or data format. wget would still work in this case, whereas SOAP would not.

Comment: I'm sure that something has changed on datasource side, as it worked before, but the guys that maintain the web service say that no other clients experiences problems with it and I thought it could be a problem on my side.